# How to load textures from a spritesheet in Godot 3

Tags: godot

I've just got started with Godot yesterday, and I'm starting a game. I drew a few spritesheets for it. It seems much more efficient to pack all of the frames of an animation into a single image file, right?

Anyway, in Godot I have an *AnimatedSprite*, who of course has a *SpriteFrames* property, or whatever it's called. I want to split my spritesheet up into multiple images so that I can use each image as a separate frame in the animation, but as far as I can see Godot provides no such feature. Is this the case?

I've been searching for an answer on the web for a while now, and I can't find anything relevant.

I'd be very surprised if I can't do this in Godot, since I can do it in just about every other game engine I've seen.

Thanks!

(Just to clarify, I want to (programmatically or otherwise,) split a spritesheet into multiple textures, within Godot.)

Answer (score 5):

Click `New SpriteFrames` in the `Frames` property menu of the `AnimatedSprite` node. Now click on the just created `SpriteFrames` next to the name of the `Frames` property. `Animation Frames` window should appear.

[image: Animation frames window screenshot]

Click this `Add frames from a Sprite Sheet` button. Select your spite sheet file, set grid sizes and finally select individual frames from that sprite sheet.

*(This works for me in Godot v3.2.2)*

Answer (score -1):

As it says: "Sprite node that can use **multiple textures** for animation."
Source: http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_animatedsprite.html

What you are searching for is using normal Sprite(2D), and set regions for it if you are using AnimationPlayer at each frame. 
Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGHcscKpA7Y

If you want to do all programmically, you just have to set the sprite to Sprite(2D), and then:

```
func _ready(): 
   set_region(true)
   set_region_rect(Rect2(positionx,positiony,width,height))
```

but i guess using AnimationPlayer is better option.

This is not tested because i should be sleeping right now, but it should work.